# Collection view drag and drop delay

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop

Is there a way to adjust time which takes for drag to begin on collection view cell? Similar to `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` `minimumPressDuration` property.

I know we can iterate over all gesture recognizers attached to the view and probably find the one we need. But this approach doesn't feel reliable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since there's no better solution, i still used 'iterate over gesture recognizers' approach.

Code is the following:

```
gestureRecognizers?.forEach { (recognizer) in
    if let longPressRecognizer = recognizer as? UILongPressGestureRecognizer {
        longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = Constants.DragLongPressMinimumDuration
    }
}
```

`Constants.DragLongPressMinimumDuration` is `Double` defined in `Constants` struct.

**Important note**: do this on collection view itself (and not cells) after setting up drag and drop.

Solution works ok for iOS versions 11 and 12.

Of course this is on the edge of using private API, actual class of that recognizer is `_UIDragLiftGestureRecognizer` (which is part of private API, and `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` subclass). But since we're casting it to `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, technically we're not using private API.

Comment: did you managed to pass the AppStore review process?