# Is there a way to reduce the time taken (long press) to initiate the drag of a collection view cell?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop, uigesturerecognizer

I've implemented drag and drop between three collection views using UICollectionViewDragDelegate and UICollectionViewDropDelegate and it seems to be working okay. The only issue is, I don't like the long press that's required to initiate the drag session. I can't find anything in the docs explaining how to override this behaviour so was wondering if one of you fine folks could help me out?

I can see a solution proposed by julsh in the following question - [Ability to shorten UIDragInteraction's long press timing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48175672/ability-to-shorten-uidraginteractions-long-press-timing) - which looks great... But I don't know how to implement it against a collection view cell?

If anyone has any ideas I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Collection view drag and drop delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53561281/collection-view-drag-and-drop-delay)

Answer (score 1):

I **found** a solution by assigning all long tap gestures of UICollectionView to
`minimumPressDuration` to 0. The final code will look like this.

```
 if let longPressRecognizer = collectionView.gestureRecognizers?.compactMap({ $0 as? UILongPressGestureRecognizer}).first {
            for val in (collectionView.gestureRecognizers?.compactMap({ $0 as? UILongPressGestureRecognizer}))!{
                val.minimumPressDuration = 0
            }
        }
```

**Remember**, write down this code below to  `collectionView.dragDelegate = self`
and  `collectionView.dropDelegate = self`.